# Prevent UIScrollView from moving contents to top-left

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` contained within a `UIScrollView`. The image is (usually) big, so the user can zoom it out in order to see the whole thing.

Upon zooming out, though, `UIScrollView` snaps the `ImageView` to the top-left of the scrollview. I want this to be positionable by the user, and haven't found a way to "turn it off" yet.

It's kinda like always allowing scrolling, rather then only allowing scrolling when the image is zoomed in. Maybe it's too major of a change?

Anyone know of a way? Originally, I was just going to create this functionality manually. But UIImageViews don't like to adjust to new sizes (I've tried about everything and can't get `UIImageView` to resize UNLESS I remove the picture from the `imageView`, change the frame, and re-add it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up disabling the `UIScrollView`'s `panGestureRecognizer` and subbing in a custom one.

Here's a quick snippet on how to disable it:

```
// Disable our GestureRecognizer
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in scrollView.gestureRecognizers){
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[gesture class]] isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer"]){
        [gesture setEnabled:NO];
        break;
    }
}
```

A bit of a hack-job there, but it's due to the fact that `UIScrollViews` have changed the class of the GestureRecognizer to "UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer." The compiler will yell at you if you try to use that class (there's probably a better solution out there).

Comment: `if ([gestureRecogniser isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer")])`

Comment: `if ([gestureRecogniser isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer")])`

Comment: There is a `panGestureRecognizer` property on `UIScrollView` as of iOS 5 that avoids this hack.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/panGestureRecognizer

Comment: Any hints on the custom method you subbed in after disabling the gesture recognizer?  I have no problems centering the image after zooming out.  But I don't want to center it.  I want to let the user position the image whether it's zoomed in or zoomed out.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you locate the `UIImageView` at location 0,0 in the `UIScrollView`, then that's always going to be the upper-left. If you want it to be centered in the scrollview when it's smaller than the view, you need to position it there. Check whether its `-size` is bigger or smaller than the scrollview's. If it's smaller than the scrollview, set its `-center` to be the same as the scrollview's.

Comment: This works perfectly for keeping the UIImageView at the center of the scrollView, but I was wondering if you knew a way to keep the UIImageView at the position it's dragged to, rather then snapping back to the center?